# How to focus the element in table2, when the element is clicked in table1 using angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 2 tables one is for Vehicles and Company. If i click on vehicle name, its corresponding company name is shown in company table..So, now i have around 12 vehicles, when i click on 12th vehicle its name is displayed on Company table, which is seen only when i scroll up.So i need to focus directly on company name instead of scrolling. Please help

Here is my HTML code for Vehicle and Company:

**Vehicle Table:**

```
<md-card *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicleLists | companyfilter:filter" (click)="goToCompany(vehicle)">
 <div >
    {{vehicle.vehicleName}}
  </div> 
   </md-card>
```

**Company Table:**

```
<md-card  *ngFor="let company of companyLists | vehiclefilter:myfilter">
 <div>
     {{company.companyName}}
 </div></md-card>
```

**TS code:**

```
goToCompany(vehicle){
this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

With the help of answer in this link, i was able to get my requirement:
[Scroll Top in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692138/scroll-top-in-angular2)

But, here it applies only with the scroll top, if the company name list is below vwhicle name, it doesnt go down. I need my requirement to work in mobile response too,In this plunker it is working fine, biut not with my code.

Plunker link: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZjZApeGBk1P6OamYv21T?p=preview
 Please Help.

Comment: I am not sure if focus function works on non-input elements. Even via vanilla JS

Comment: Thank for replying. What can be used so that i meet my requirement? Please help

Comment: Let me understand the requirements first. You would like to automatically scroll the 2nd table up as soon as the link of the first table is clicked correct?

Comment: if i scroll il get the company name.. without scrolling up only it must focus it to there.. It is like i have 12 vehicle names so the table of vehicle will be more and respective company entry will be only one.. so company name will be in 1st row in Company table where as vehicle will be in 12th row. So instead of scrolling and seeing, it must get focused on 1st row of company name

Comment: Not an angular2 user but this may help https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-set-focus-element/

Comment: So i need to write ts code n all ?

Comment: If you like. I can't tell for sure if

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151233/discussion-between-tulsi-and-sagar).

Comment: @Sagar: as u said before, focus is not working in angular2.. Is there anyother method ?

Comment: Sorry. Out of ideas for this one. Maybe someone else with more expertise could help

Comment: Thanks for helping:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve focus functionality for non-input elements using the following approaches

1. using the anchor tags
2. adding tabindex attribute to non-input elements

you can access your non-input elements in Angular 2 using the @Viewchild and Renderer or ElementRef

```js
import --> AfterViewInit

 export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild('companyTable') vc: any;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.vc.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<md-card class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" *ngFor="let company of companyLists | vehiclefilter:myfilter">
 <div #companyTable tabindex="0" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;">
     {{company.companyName}}
 </div></md-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i will try

Comment: Sorry it is not scrolling top, when i click on 12th vehicle, it must scroll top and show the company name. Please help

Comment: Please refer following example

https://plnkr.co/edit/93xihP4APBFKRAImE1SU?p=preview

Comment: Thanks i will try

Comment: if it is focusing then will definitely scroll up to the active element. if it in loop then it should be handle with index. lem me share another example.

Comment: ya please, help me.. im not getting how to solve this

Comment: There are many ways to solve the problem , This is one way
I have created a example with dummy data, please use the following one for reference.
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZjZApeGBk1P6OamYv21T?p=preview

lem me know if you face any issues

Comment: Ya sure.. Thank you soo much

Comment: I need my code to work same as your plunker, but i have long list of vehicle names with only one company name..

Comment: You have vehicle and company, one below the other.. but my vehicle and compnay is side by side.. and to one vehicle one company name is displayed, when i click on any of the Vehicle name then that particular comapany name is displayed one at a time

Comment: If all the companies are holding same company name, you can handle with index from loop. or else if i have the json format i can give best solution.

Comment: Now i edited as u showed in plunker.. il check whether its working or not. It is not working.. showing syntax errors n full page is gone.. I am not getting where im gng wrong

Comment: hai, i got output according to my requirement but it is not working with mobile response.. pls help

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why pressing on a vehiclerow should focus on the company row. Should not a click on a vehicle row logically lead you to the vehicle details page?

If you have the company name on the vehicle object you could.

*In the Company list*

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
         <span id="{{company.companyName}}">{{company.companyName}}/span>
   </div>
```

*In the vehicle list*. Add a new anchor that shows the componyname direct. Pressing on this link starts the scroll to company table

```
<a href="#{{vehicle.companyName}}">{{vehicle.companyName}}</a>
```

You could also add a small floating div on the company anchor in the vehicle list that show the most important company data. So you dont need to focus away from the vehicle list. First when you click the anchor you should navigate away

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try

Comment: Sorry I have a typo there. It should ofcource be: <a href="#{{vehicle.companyName}}">{{vehicle.companyName}}</a> I will update the answer

Comment: ya i will try and tell you

Comment: i tried but not working.. it is not focusing instead it is going up

Comment: Ok so you can see both tables at the same time? You dont have to scroll upp in the page? The anchor tag solves the scroll. When it comes to focus on a display label i would say its not possible because its not a input field. BUT you can use ngClass to style it. 1. When you press on the anchorlink i suggested above you can add a (click)="onCompanyNameClick(company.companyName). In that metod you could add {this.selectedComponyName =companyName} in the componay table you could do a ngClass check on the member. And add a class with any background color or style.

Comment: pls help, im very new to angular2.. not getting to solve.. i will update my question

Comment: <span id="{{company.companyName}}" [ngClass]="{'focused':selectedComponyName==company.companyName }>{{company.companyName}}</span>.    Then add a class named focused to you stylesheet. ex: .focused{background-color:blue;color:#fff}. Now it should 'jump' up to position and color the label

Comment: i will try and let you no

Comment: If im not wrong. You can't see the vehicle table and compoany table at the same time. Becasue it scrolls up and down the page. Could you not just create to pages? One with the vehicle and one with the componies? You could navigate between the pages when you click och anchors. But you need a good id for the records.

Comment: you are right i cant see both tables at once. And no i cant make to other pages. when both tables are seen at once, scroll top works fine.. but when tables are one below the other, issue is arising