# Does not display scroll top icon on chrome in angular4?

Tags: angular

I have use scrollTop in angular2. But does not display chrome browser.

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll Top in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43692138/scroll-top-in-angular2)

Comment: can you please share your code ? also have you added CSS for icon ? also when you define to show your icon ?

Comment: might help you https://embed.plnkr.co/kzZ2VR/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 $(window).scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: As per question icon is not displaying, and in your code when is icon may i know ?

Comment: Can you please tell me, have you ever see any icon of scrollTop in your programming career?  It is a property

Comment: FYI some packages display icon on click of that icon you will move to top of screen, for example in React this package offer same icon `react-scroll-up` , also i know very well it is property and `document.body.scrollTop = 0;
` is also right one.

Comment: and in the question it is clearly mention `Does not display scroll top icon ...`